# Trap attempt to send Woocommerce mail without To:

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

My Woocommerce shop allows to buy for anonymous customers without email address.
One of allowed payment method is online card payment.
I added blind copy to notification mail to allow admin know about payment:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_headers', function ($header, $email_id, $order) {
    if ('customer_processing_order' === $email_id) {
        $header .= "BCC: MyShopAdmin <myshopadmin@domain.net>";
    }
    return $header;
}, 10, 3);
```

Works great when customer entered email during checkout process.

None of email when customer not entered email address. Yes, it's reasonable - no email address = no email.

But I want to inform shop admin about successful payment even no customer email address entered. How to do it?

Guess exists some point in Woocommerce where I can analyze email headers early before mail send init. I did not find any hooks / filters for that.
Does anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of adding filter at woocommerce_email_headers why dont you try woocommerce_payment_complete hook

This would facilitate shop admin about successful payment event

add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'payment_complete' );

Comment: Looks like a way to create and send completely new mail / notification.
Ok, but is it possible to use standard mail by form "Payment done" (similar to this)?

Comment: When customer doesn't not enter email, definitely woocommerce_email_headers filter wont get invoked, and hence you do not have an option but to hook woocommerce_payment_complete